# UWP and Windows Store 8.1 biometric authorization

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, biometrics

We have an app, that uses email + password for log in. For comfort we have implemented 4 digit PIN code logic. All this logic is self-created, not using any microsoft built in features.

On 1 device may be many users.So we would like to implement also a possibility for biometric auth.

I have googled for the info and it seems, that all biometric authorization options are based on Microsoft account.

I have imagined something like:

```
var hash = GetBiometricHash(); 
// reuqest user to make biometric authorization and the hash we could store on our servers.
```

Is there such possibility or we will have to integrate the Microsoft accounts usage?

Answer (score 0):

You could add [fingerprint biometrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/fingerprint-biometrics) to your Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app by the following code. Including a request for fingerprint authentication when the user must consent to a particular action increases the security of your app. But if you change to another device that has no your fingerprint information. The application will not be able to certify your fingerprint. Currently there is no such api for saving your fingerprint  information to your own web service. So you could integrate the [Microsoft accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport) usage.

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> RequestConsent(string 
userMessage)
{
string returnMessage;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userMessage))
{
    userMessage = "Please provide fingerprint verification.";
}

try
{
    // Request the logged on user's consent via fingerprint swipe.
    var consentResult = await Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerifier.RequestVerificationAsync(userMessage);

    switch (consentResult)
    {
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.Verified:
            returnMessage = "Fingerprint verified.";
            break;
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.DeviceBusy:
            returnMessage = "Biometric device is busy.";
            break;
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.DeviceNotPresent:
            returnMessage = "No biometric device found.";
            break;
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.DisabledByPolicy:
            returnMessage = "Biometric verification is disabled by policy.";
            break;
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.NotConfiguredForUser:
            returnMessage = "The user has no fingerprints registered. Please add a fingerprint to the " +
                            "fingerprint database and try again.";
            break;
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.RetriesExhausted:
            returnMessage = "There have been too many failed attempts. Fingerprint authentication canceled.";
            break;
        case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.Canceled:
            returnMessage = "Fingerprint authentication canceled.";
            break;
        default:
            returnMessage = "Fingerprint authentication is currently unavailable.";
            break;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    returnMessage = "Fingerprint authentication failed: " + ex.ToString();
}

return returnMessage;
}
```